# Responsive website showing large screen view on high pixel density mobile devices

Tags: html, responsive-design, media-queries, web-deployment, mobile-website

Using *media query* I created different views for different pixel count screens. But now on small screens with high pixel count (like iPhone5, S3, S4) desktop view is shown.

**How can I show small screen view i. e. `520px` view on these HD screen mobiles?**

Some meta tag or whatever html that can help is welcomed.

Comment: please post that `not working` code here or in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<header>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</header>
```

### css

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 320px)
and (max-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these two lines on top of your HTML File.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```